# Docker-compose container: how to alias port?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I had used Adminer in Docker (from standard [image](https://hub.docker.com/_/adminer/)) with `docker-compose`:

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'
services:
  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
```

`/etc/hosts` (in main system):

```
172.19.0.6  adminer.ll
```

It worked fine, when i typed `adminer.ll:8080` into browser, I got Adminer.

Then I decided, that I want this address to be only `adminer.ll` without the port `8080` (it means change exposed port from `8080` to `80`).

So I changed `ports` parameter:

```
version: '2'
services:
  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '80:8080'
```

But it is not working. When I type `adminer.ll` into browser, it can't connect. Interesting is, that `adminer.ll:8080` is still working.

Port `8080` is exposed by `EXPOSE` directive from Adminer image. But why doesn't my `ports` parameter translate it to `80`? Am I missing something?

Output of `docker-compose ps`:

```
          Name                         Command               State          Ports        
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
docker_adminer_1            entrypoint.sh docker-php-e ...   Up      0.0.0.0:80->8080/tcp
```

It looks like it is listening for all IPs and translating port `80` to port `8080`, but it is not.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you have `172.19.0.6  adminer.ll` in your hosts file and not `127.0.0.1 adminer.ll`? Are you not running docker-compose locally?

Comment: Also can you try `ports: - 127.0.0.1:80:80` instead of just `ports: - '8080:8080'` in you compose yaml ?

Comment: Make sure that you don't have another service on the host that is already listening to port 80. Do a `sudo netstat -tpln` to see what's listening to what.

Comment: @kfedorov91 I am running it locally. I have it there, because I suppose, that this is container's IP address, which it received. When I run `docker inspect docker_adminer_1 | grep IPAddress\"`, I see `"IPAddress": "172.19.0.2"`, so I copied it to `etc/hosts`

Comment: When you deleted and recreated the container, its IP address changed.  You should probably never be looking up the Docker-internal IP address.

Comment: @DavidMaze I agree, this is disadvantage and I need to update IP in /etc/hosts eventually. But what do you suggest? Now I have `adminer.ll` pointing to `127.0.0.1` and other domains to 172.19.0.x. If I point other domains also to localhost, I will see only Adminer...

Comment: Never set anything in `/etc/hosts`.  Use `docker run -p` to expose a port on the host.  Use the host's DNS name and the exposed port to access the service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@kfedorov91's comment solved this:

> Why do you have 172.19.0.6 adminer.ll in your hosts file and not 127.0.0.1 adminer.ll? Are you not running docker-compose locally?

I only inserted `127.0.0.1 adminer.ll` and deleted previous IP address and when I go to `adminer.ll` I can see Adminer. Thanks.

Note: it looks like "translation" ports (thanks to `ports` property) is taking place on "outside" network, so it is used only if I use 127.0.0.1 for reaching the container. If I use direct IP of container, it is not applied.

Note 2: I am also routing other local domains to some docker containers via theirs "direct IPs" (something like 172.19.0.x). It works fine because they use implicitly standard port 80. If I try to change their routing to 127.0.0.1, I see Adminer. This is what is @Alkaline pointing out in comment, I suppose.

Thank you, guys.